# Transforming NetCDF into JSON using Python for dynamic display (with movement) using JavaScript

Tags: python, javascript, netcdf, json

I have NetCDF data and am trying to transform this into JSON, using Python, to then use in a web sig (NCWMS server).

By transforming this into JSON, could I display this same data dynamically (with movement) with the use of JavaScript?

Comment: It would be **very** unusual to convert raster data like NetCDF into JSON which is a text based "human" readable format and would be huge for any reasonably sized raster. I would expect NCWMS to read NetCDF natively

Comment: Try WCS / OAPI Coverages to CIS JSON / CoverageJSON

Comment: Actually, I fully agree with you. The problem is that I have a proposal to make this data dynamic, something like what we can see on windy's website.

So, I don't know what to do in this case.

Comment: The only place to "talk" with someone on this site is in a generic chat room like the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) (which needs a reputation of 20) or a special purpose one.  Although limited discussion can take place in comments on posts.  Consequently, I'm removing the last sentence from your question so that it can be focused on the particular question you wish to ask.